# Assigning value to a random word in Django

Tags: python, django, view, model

I need a little help how to go about doing this. I have created a poll that randomly generates a question, say "How do you like 'Blue'?" The user will rate it from 1-5. A new question will appear such as "How do you like 'Green'?" 
The words are randomly pulled from an array.

How do I begin to write a view/model to **store the value** selected by the user for each word?
The output should look something like this (the scores would be averaged for each color):

```
Blue 3.4
Green 4.1
Red 2.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Model to store your colors:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = CharField(...)
```

and store your colors there.

To make it rateable just use one of the great rating plugins for Django, for example [django-ratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings). Of course you can also create your own rating app, but I think there is a planty of them already on the internet, so why don't use one?

hth

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you should either put the color in a hidden field or store it in a session (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/ for that)

In order to have an average, your model must either store all the votes or store the current average + the number of votes cast so far, so that you can calculate the new average as

```
new_avg = ((old_avg * votes) + new_vote) / (votes++))
```

For handling POST requests, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST